# Is there a CSS3 filter to turn colors with gradients into solid colors

Tags: css, colors, radial-gradients, css-filters, css-mask

I have a special case in which I use a `-webkit-mask` with a `radial-gradient` to create little dots on a background picture. The color of these dots is `transparent` so that the background picture can be seen within the dots.

Now there is the case that the color in each dot has a gradient.

Is there a possibility to detect the average color in each dot and apply a CSS filter which shows a solid color?

So what I want is when I have a dot with shades of blue, then I want to apply a filter that just shows a solid blue color.

Here is a screenshot of such a case:

[image]

Is this possible with CSS without adding a separate div for each dot and setting the CSS background color manually? Or do I need to play around with WebGL?

Comment: Can you post some example code?

Answer (score 0):

With blend properties, you can use only the hue value from the underlying div

In this demo, the base element has a gradient. the overlay removes the variation in luminosity, applying the overlay luminosity

```css
div {
    height: 200px;
}
.base {
    width: 300px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(hsl(120, 50%, 60%),hsl(120, 100%, 90%));
}
.overlay {
   position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    top: 10px;
    z-index: 2;
    border: solid 1px black;
    background-color: gray;
    mix-blend-mode: luminosity;
}
```

```html
<div class="base"></div>
<div class="overlay"></div>
```